# Escape the cube puzzle

Tags: no-computers, board-games

**Hello,**

here is a puzzle I created. I plan to post a few more in the near future. If you like it, google Cubiscape for more.

**Goal:**

You are the blue ball and have to get to the green square without being caught by the red cube.

[image]

**Rules:**

- Game is turn based.
- Each turn you can move by one tile and the red cube can move by two (does not have to be in the same direction). You move first. You cannot skip your move.
- Moves are only possible horizontally (left/right) or vertically (up/down).
- The red cube is chasing you. It will always seek to get closer to you. If it can choose from either going horizontally or vertically, it will always prefer going horizontally. If any available move would put it further away from you, it will not move. If it ever reaches the tile you are standing on, you lose.
- When you reach the green tile, the red cube still gets to do its two moves. If it reaches you, you still lose.

**Additional clarifications:**

- Whoever enters the teleport (upwards from your starting location) is instantly transported to the tile marked with "T".
- The red cube is oblivious to the teleport - it treats it as a regular tile when deciding where to move. It will be teleported normally though.

**What is the shortest sequence of moves to win?**

Comment: Interesting variant on a [Theseus and the Minotaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theseus_and_the_Minotaur) maze.

Comment: Interesting! This is truly very similar. I have many more special tiles to make it interesting, but seeing the original idea si nice. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this takes nine moves

> Right, Left. The Red cube takes the teleporter

followed by

> Left, Up, Up, Right. The red cube teleports again.

and finally

> Left, Left, Left to complete the maze.

Comment: Correct! That was pretty fast :) Tomorrow i will post something slightly harder.

Comment: Good job.  I thought I had eight but messed it up and my solution ended up devolving to yours.